# Update ActionLink HTML Attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

a lot of the answers I've seen here, or elsewhere, have all used conditional `if` statements with data passed from the `Controller` to the `View` which isn't how I'm able to do this.

I have an `ActionLink` on my page which is shown or hidden based on a drop down value selected.   The `jquery` I used is as follows

```
$(function checkTotalRows() {
    if ($('#productParameters>tr').length > 0) {
        var link = document.getElementById('AddNewItem');
        $('#AddNewItem').hide();

    } else {
        $('#AddNewItem').show();
    }
});
```

This will show / hide the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Product", "AddProduct", new { productId= ?}, new {@id="AddNewItem" })
```

The problem I have is with the `HTML attribute` where I've listed `new { productId = ? }`, I don't know how to set this via `jquery` or even if this is possible?  The ? when giving the value of productId is just my way of saying in this post I don't know what, other than explicity stating Model.something, should go there.

Is there some way that I can pass an ID to this attribute?

Comment: I don't know ASP but it seems you want to add an attribute to an HTML element with jquery if it is then yes there is a way - $('select_element').attr('myattrname','myattrvalue');

Comment: Can you elaborate, Where you are trying to pass value to productId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `-1` instead of `?` in `new { productId= -1}`. Basically use `-1` as placeholder which you can replace latter with youre desired product id

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New Product", "AddProduct", new { productId= -1}, new {@id="AddNewItem" })
```

To replace it use Using jQuery [**.prop()**](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) function, you can fetch href attribute and update it like

```
var elem = $('#AddNewItem');
var newUrl = elem.prop('href').replace('-1', 'YourProductId');
elem.prop('href', newUrl);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my post (I've updated it) the ? was only to state that I don't know what should do there, normally I would put my Model.Something

Comment: @MattR, I have given you example to how to updated href using jQuery. You can try it. I am more concerned with How you want to use example given above?

Comment: I just got the chance to give it a try, that worked like an absolute charm.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you think there is only one `Id=AddNewItem` in a page and if you have a product id set in your model

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Add New Product",
    actionName: "AddProduct",
    controllerName: "Product",
    routeValues: new {
        productId= Model.ProductId
    },
    new {@id="AddNewItem"}
)
```